# Laplace transform using numerical integration in Python has very poor precision

Tags: python, scipy, complex-numbers, numerical-integration, mpmath

I have written a function to compute the Laplace transform of a function using `scipy.integrate.quad`. It is not a very sophisticated function and currently performs poorly on the probability density function of an Erlang distribution.

I have included all my work below. I first compute the Laplace transform and then the inverse in order to compare it to the original p.d.f. of the Erlang. I use `mpmath` for this. The `mpmath.invertlaplace` is not the problem as it manages to convert the closed-form Laplace transform back to the original p.d.f. quite perfectly.

Please help me understand what the problem is with my numerical laplace transform. I get the following error but have not been able to resolve it.

`IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents the requested tolerance from being achieved. The error may be underestimated. a=0,b=np.inf,limit=limit)[0]`

**PLOT**

[image]

**CODE**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m
import mpmath as mp
import scipy.stats as st
from scipy.integrate import quad


def get_laplace(func,limit=10000):
    
    '''
    Returns laplace transfrom function
    '''
    
    def laplace(s):
        '''Numerical laplace transform'''
        # Seperate into real and imaginary parts
        x = np.real(s)
        y = np.imag(s)
        
        def real_func(t):
            return m.exp(-x*t)*m.cos(y*t)*func(t)
        
        def imag_func(t):
            return m.exp(-x*t)*m.sin(y*t)*func(t)
        
        real_integral = quad(real_func,
                             a=0,b=np.inf,limit=limit)[0]
        
        imag_intergal = quad(real_func,
                             a=0,b=np.inf,limit=limit)[0]
        
        return complex(real_integral,-imag_intergal)
    
    return laplace
        

def L_erlang(s,lam,k):
    '''
    Closed form laplace transform of Erlang or Gamma distribution.
    '''
    return (lam/(lam+s))**k


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # Setup Erlang probability density function
    k = 5
    lam = 1
    pdf = st.erlang(a=k,scale=1/lam).pdf
    
    # Laplace transforms
    Lnum = get_laplace(pdf)          # numerical approximation
    L = lambda s: L_erlang(s,lam,k)  # closed form
    
    
    # Use mpmath library to perform inverse laplace
    
    # Invserse transfrom on numerical laplace function
    invLnum = lambda t: mp.invertlaplace(Lnum,t,
                                         method='dehoog',
                                         dps=5, 
                                         degree=3)
    
    # Invserse transfrom on closed-form laplace function
    invL = lambda t: mp.invertlaplace(L,t,
                                      method='dehoog',
                                      dps=5, 
                                      degree=3)
    
    # Grid to visualise
    T = np.linspace(0.1,10,10)
    # Get values of inverse transforms
    lnum = np.array([invLnum(t) for t in T])
    l = np.array([invL(t) for t in T])
    
    # Plot
    plt.plot(T,lnum,label='from numerical laplace')
    plt.plot(T,l,label='from closed-form laplace')
    plt.plot(T,pdf(T),label='original pdf',linestyle='--')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()
```

**UPDATE**

After two cups of VERY strong coffee, I managed to see the obvious mistake and make the code work. It quite embarrassing actually. Have a look at this line of code:

```
imag_intergal = quad(real_func,
                     a=0,b=np.inf,limit=limit)[0]
```

Hmmm, `real_func` hey? So it should read:

```
imag_intergal = quad(imag_func_func,
                     a=0,b=np.inf,limit=limit)[0]
```

The one gets this lovely plot:

[image]

**Conclusion**
So why go through all the trouble to numerically perform the Laplace transform of something that we have a closed form solution for. That is because the interest lies somewhere else. We do not have a closed expression for the conditional future lifetime distribution which is similar to the hazard function. Lets call it `h`. Then for the Erlang distribution `erl = st.erlang(a=k,scale=1/lam)` that has been active for `tau` units of time we have `h = lambda t: erl.pdf(t+tau)/erl.sf(tau)`. This distribution can be used as a holding time in a Semi-Markov Model (SMP). To analyse the transient behaviour of the SMP one use Laplace transforms. Usually only pdfs are used but now I can use hazard functions. Its pretty cool because it means one can model transient behaviour without assuming everything is new.

Comment: Best answer your own question and accept the answer, this way people see that this is "resolved". (Right now, the overview just shows a question with zero replies.)

Comment: @Nico Schlömer--Isn't this the the responsibility of SO?  Or are we pretending SO is a public utility?  "Stack Exchange, Inc. has **35 total employees** across all of its locations and **generates $20.41 million in sales** (USD)." -- https://www.dnb.com/business-directory/company-profiles.stack_exchange_inc.c2b217909c04f38a07ef1f9397f21b87.html  So manipulating folks to work for free, instead of using some of that 20M$ to hire people, seems unethical to me.  Did I miss something?  I'm trying to understand the moral justification.  It almost seems like theft.

Comment: @Andrew OP asked a question, came up with an answer before anyone else did, and simply added the answer to the question. It should rather be a reply.

Comment: I agree;  my point is that the OP, AFAIK, is not employed by SO.  So "should" under what moral code?  SO, IMHO, "should" do a lot of things.  It seems if you have , inc; .com; etc. after your name then you can dictate theses "shoulds".  When's my tern to re-define morality?  I'd suggest if you feel strongly then post it yourself, iff that makes sense to you.  :-)

Comment: Hello everyone. I feel immoral towards answering my own questions and marking the as correct. I always hope that someone might come up with an alternative solution. However, I can see the purpose of answering my own question as to get it marked as resolved. I appreciate this perspective. As such, the questions is now resolved.

Comment: Nico is right.  All this talk about re-defining morality is useless nonsense.  Answering and accepting your own answer is the norm here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day. I am repeating the **Updates** section from the original questions as this is the solution to the questions. This way, the questions can be marked as resolved.

**UPDATE**

After two cups of VERY strong coffee, I managed to see the obvious mistake and make the code work. It quite embarrassing actually. Have a look at this line of code:

```
imag_intergal = quad(real_func,
                     a=0,b=np.inf,limit=limit)[0]
```

Hmmm, `real_func` hey? So it should read:

```
imag_intergal = quad(imag_func_func,
                     a=0,b=np.inf,limit=limit)[0]
```

The one gets this lovely plot:

[image]

**Conclusion**
So why go through all the trouble to numerically perform the Laplace transform of something that we have a closed form solution for. That is because the interest lies somewhere else. We do not have a closed expression for the conditional future lifetime distribution which is similar to the hazard function. Lets call it `h`. Then for the Erlang distribution `erl = st.erlang(a=k,scale=1/lam)` that has been active for `tau` units of time we have `h = lambda t: erl.pdf(t+tau)/erl.sf(tau)`. This distribution can be used as a holding time in a Semi-Markov Model (SMP). To analyse the transient behaviour of the SMP one use Laplace transforms. Usually only pdfs are used but now I can use hazard functions. Its pretty cool because it means one can model transient behaviour without assuming everything is new.